# Dynamically print number of rows updated

Tags: c#, sql

The company that I work for has large databases, millions of records in a single table. I have written a C# program that migrates tables between remote servers.

I first create all the tables using SMO without copying data and then the data insertion is done after all the tables have been created.

During the record insertion since there are so many records the console window remains blank until all the rows have been inserted. Due to the sheer volumes of data this takes a long time.

What I want now is a way to print n rows updated like in MSSQL import export data wizard.
The insert part is just a simple `insert into select *` query.

Comment: How are you doing the inserts? SqlBulkCopy? Plain old SqlCommand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to look on [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause. There are useful examples on MSDN.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr) )
{
    var sqlCmd = "
                  CREATE TABLE #tmp (
                      InsertedId BIGINT                                             
                  );
                  INSERT INTO TestTable
                  OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO #tmp
                  VALUES ....
                  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd,conn))
    {
        conn .Open();
        var numRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Affected Rows: {0}",numRows);
    }
}
```

Also I suggest to use stored procedure for such purposes.

Comment: it needs to look like this  1 rows updated 2 rows updated .... n rows updated but not it separate lines.

Comment: The insert takes a long time to run so I need this kind of output to show my boss that the data is being migrated and this is the current status.

Comment: You can create table for such logging purposes. And instead of writing output to #tmp table write it into logging table. Meanwhile another process will just query this table and refresh progress.

Comment: are there no other solution for this?

Comment: Ok, I tried this and it works, though it makes my code lengthy. The problem now is that some tables have more than 100 columns, so OUTPUT INSERTED.* is not really appealing. Is there a way to insert just an integer value- 1 into a table for every row inserted?

Comment: @Ejaz You can `OUTPUT 1 INTO SomeTable`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be using SqlCommands, if so here is a sample

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection.ConnectionString) )
{
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into  OldCustomers select * from customers",connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var numRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine("Affected Rows: {0}",numRows);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already done this.But as I said this is not what I want the number of rows updated must change dynamically as each row is being inserted.